# Compilation failed during instrumentation of solidity-coverage

Tags: solidity, truffle

Getting compilation failed error, while running solidity-coverage.  Truffle compile is working fine.

Here is my truffle config:

```js
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    coverage: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      network_id: 5777,
      port: 8555,
      gas: 0xfffffffffff,
      gasPrice: 0x01
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: '0.5.10',
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 200
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: ["solidity-coverage"]
};
```

`.solcover.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  port: 8555,
  norpc: true,
  deepSkip: true,
  compileCommand: '../node_modules/.bin/truffle compile',
  testCommand: 'node --max-old-space-size=4096 ../node_modules/.bin/truffle test --network coverage',
  skipFiles: [
    'imports',
    'EventCaller.sol',
    'dummyDaiFeed.sol',
    'mocks'
  ],
  forceParse: [
    'imports/ERC1132',
    'mocks'
  ]
};
```

Command used to run coverage: `node_modules/.bin/solidity-coverage`

Getting this error only while running coverage:

```
* Line 1, Column 1
  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.
* Line 1, Column 2
  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.
Compilation failed. See above.
```

Error occurred during the compilation after the instrumentation was completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated .solcover.js
As per the gitter conversation in solidity-coverage channel, i got to know that there is some error while instrumention oraclize contract.
So added the 'external' folder to **skipFiles**, in which oraclize contract is residing.

```
module.exports = {
  skipFiles: ['external', 'EventCaller.sol', 'dummyDaiFeed.sol', 'mocks'],
  providerOptions: {
    default_balance_ether: 10000000000, // Extra zero, coverage consumes more gas
    network_id: 5777,
    mnemonic:
      'grocery obvious wire insane limit weather parade parrot patrol stock blast ivory',
    total_accounts: 30
  }
};
```

And now coverage tool is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
compileCommand: '../node_modules/.bin/truffle compile',
testCommand: 'node --max-old-space-size=4096 ../node_modules/.bin/truffle test --network coverage',
```

To this:

```
compileCommand: 'node ../node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js compile --network=coverage',
testCommand: 'node --max-old-space-size=4096 ../node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js test --network=coverage',
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Tried changing, still getting same error